# How can I make UIAlertController appear over the top of anything and everything?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uialertcontroller, visual-studio-2022

I am developing an app using Visual Studio 2022 that uses `ZXing.Net.Mobile,Forms` to scan barcodes, everything is working as expected except I am unable to display the UIAlertController message over the top of everything.  My code is:

```
        btnScan.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            // First we must get permission to use the camera
            AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.GetAuthorizationStatus(AVAuthorizationMediaType.Video);

            if (authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
            {
                scan();
            }
            else if (authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
            {
                Utils.ShowMessage(this,"Camera access not determined. Ask for permission.", "Error");

                AVCaptureDevice.RequestAccessForMediaType(AVAuthorizationMediaType.Video, (granted) =>
                {
                    if (granted)
                    {
                        scan();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        camDenied();
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatus.Restricted)
            {
                Utils.ShowMessage(this, "This device doesn't have the camera feature", "Error");
            }
            else
            {
                // Denied
                camDenied();
            }
        };
    }

    void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        var msg = "";

        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
            msg = "Found Barcode: " + result.Text;
        else
            msg = "Scanning Canceled!";

        // I need this alert to appear over the top of everything
        InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            Utils.ShowMessage(this, msg, "Scan Success");
        });
    }
    void camDenied()
    {
        UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create("Warning", "It looks like your privacy settings are preventing us from accessing your camera. You can fix this by doing the following...", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        UIAlertAction goAction = UIAlertAction.Create("Go", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) =>
        {
            // Open Settings 
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString));
        });
        alert.AddAction(goAction);

        PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }

    void scan ()
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.NavigationController);
            scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
            var opt = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions() { DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 3000 };
            scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode to scan";
            scanner.BottomText = "Barcode will automatically scan";

            //Start scanning
            scanner.ScanContinuously(opt, false, HandleScanResult);
        });
    }
```

The `UIAlertController` code executes without an error but no alert appears.  Is there a way to force the alert to appear over the top of everything?

Comment: Are you calling your AlertController on MainThread, in case it's not on it already? Since PresentViewController needs to be executed on Main. If that's not the case call the present controller method from the current VC

Comment: I believe I am.  I transition from one View to another where the scan button is located, I'm not doing that on another thread.  I believe that ZXing does appear on another thread, but I cannot be 100% sure of that.

Comment: I also attempted this code `          CoreFoundation.DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => {                 Utils.ShowMessage(this, msg, "Scan Success");   });`  with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.  I changed my `Utils.ShowMessage` function as follows:

```
    public static void ShowMessage(UIViewController myview, string message, string messagetype)
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        var vc = window.RootViewController;
        while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
        }

        var okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(message, messagetype, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
        vc.PresentViewController(okAlertController, true, null);
    }
```

One needs to get the root view controller and display the alert from that.